# Graph/Chart based on amount per price

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to draw a block graph line and it should show me the amount each block has and that the total equals to a certain number.

Example:   [Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PsMNs_1JK1GvfNHnKz_fk9GHH8oGVj6sjfXyCZvmDKM/edit?usp=sharing)

I have 5000 items and would like to sell them for a certain price per item.
I want the total of the items to be, 10000$ when they are all sold.

Based on a line in the graph (drawn manually) I know which sells for 10$ and which sells for 100$ as long as the total is, 10000$

How would I approach this and is there a tool for this?

If this is the wrong channel? Where should I go to with this question?

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Do you have a table for your example? Do you enter the sells manually?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid it isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. An example or screenshot would help. What is on the x and y axis? Are you updating the sales live, and use this "line" to determine how many items you may still sell at the lower price?

Comment: @mobus yes the sale should actually be updated live because the price will be determined on price per bid. That's a good one to add to the question! Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a small data set (in your question, not as a link) and the corresponding chart?

Comment: Looking at your example image, why is the line going up and down and up again and then down again? I am unsure what is based on existing sale data (ie. already sold 26 items at $20 each) or what is the "answer" that you are looking for? I.e. What should the price be for the next sale of x items?

Comment: I want to draw the curve and that should define the amount per item keeping it below the total of the amount.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you want to do. Do you want to draw a graph my hand / using your mouse in excel (using i.e. an insert line shape) or perhaps another software, then have that graph "digitised" to get actual numbers from there?

Comment: Correct within the bounds of the total amount!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem: How to hand draw a line graph and convert it into numbers in Excel:**

If you have a graph as an image / photo / bitmap / scanned in e.g. PDF or JPG format, the process of digitally extracting the x and y values from that graph is called **graph digitization**. There are a few paid and freeware programs that do this. One of these I have used successfully to digitise graphs from old scanned journal articles in PDF format. It was called [Engauge Digitizer](http://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/) and work fairly well for certain types of graphs.

**A solution: Third party digitizer software**

For your application, you might draw the graph in Paint and then digitise the image in Engauge, export to csv and import to excel, then apply formula to cap it to the maximum total - BUT I suspect it might just be too time consuming and not worth the effort.

**Another solution: Old Excel MPOC**

Excel 2003 and prior had a feature called MPOC (manipulate points on chart). Here you could say start off with a straight line and drag the points with the mouse until you have a curve you are happy with. The chart source data in the cells would automatically adjust as you drag the points.

This would have be a nice solution for you, but unfortunately MPOC has been depreciated in newer versions of Excel. There was an official [MPOC add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2009/11/02/excel-add-in-for-manipulating-points-on-charts-mpoc/#:%7E:text=The%20Manipulate%20Points%20on%20Charts,like%20to%20hear%20from%20you.) which restores some of the functionality, but I saw at least one forum post stating that this add-in does not work for Excel 2016 or newer. There is [another way](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/how-do-i-manually-move-the-point-on-a-graph-so-it-changes-the/m-p/1117548) of inserting an old Excel graph object into a MS Word or Excel document. This graph object still has MPOC, but the source data exists in this strange data table (a separate window to the normal Excel or Word doc) and must be manually copied and pasted into Excel in order to do anything with the data.

**VBA Solution:**

You could insert line shapes (even free-hand shapes) into Excel as floating shape objects. Using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) code, you can then write a macro that reads the x and y coordinates of the shapes and decode those into cell data. This is an advanced method and probably not worth the effort, but would give the most accurate results.

**A rough Excel approximation solution:**

You could use a grid of say 100x100 cells, size the cells to be square, and zoom out. "Draw" your line shape by entering a "1" in each cell. Now at the bottom, put a formula to detect the position of the 1, e.g.:

```
=(100-MATCH(1,A1:A100,0))/99*scale
```

Where scale is the maximum value in your graph e.g. 500.